# I want to write Angular js ng-minlength validator in my own js file to validate the minlength

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and need some clarification.

```
 <input type="text" 
    placeholder="Name" 
    name="name" 
    ng-model="signup.name" 
    ng-minlength=3 
    ng-maxlength=20 required />
```

is there any method to remove **ng-minlength** from the tag and write in my external js file to work?

Comment: Why don't you try directive ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom directive that uses the `NgModelController` and add a custom validator to it.
Look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) at the `$validators` property.

As an example of validator that could fit :

```
ngModel.$validators.isLongEnough = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  var value = modelValue || viewValue;
  return value.length >= 3;
};
```